# Jquery countdown with synchronous ajax call issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, countdown

There is a bid website on some products, and there is a countdown timer that should calculate the remaining time with respect to the server time.

Following is the jQuery for the countdown and notice the attribute serverSync that is calling an ajax function called serverTime() to get the server time.

```
//Countdown Jquery
$(".anything").countdown("change", {
    until: $.countdown.UTCDate(0, year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, 0),
    format:"dHMS",
    serverSync: serverTime
});

//The ajax function that is being called by the countdown script
function serverTime() { 
    var time = null; 
    $.ajax({
        url: "serverTime.php", 
        async: false, 
        dataType: "text", 
        success: function(text) { 
            time = new Date(text); 
        }, error: function(http, message, exc) { 
            time = new Date(); 
        }
    }); 
    return time; 
}
```

When opening the page with the countdown from different PCs, the countdown stops working as expected. When I remove `async: false` from the AJAX function `serverTime()`, the countdown works fine but it shows different timers on different PCs since it will take the PC time and not the SERVER time.

I need a solution for this.

Comment: **Never use synchronous A(asynchronous!!!)JAX request.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking the following solution

```
//Countdown Jquery
$(".anything").countdown("change", {
    until: $.countdown.UTCDate(0, year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, 0),
    format:"dHMS",
    serverSync: serverTime
});

//The ajax function that is being called by the countdown script
function serverTime() {         
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: "serverTime.php", 
        async: false, 
        dataType: "text", 
        type: "GET", // or "POST"
    });

    // 'async' has to be 'false' for this to work
    var response = {valid: jqxhr.statusText,  data: jqxhr.responseText};

    if (response.valid == 'OK')
    {
        return new Date(response.data);
    }
    else
    {
        alert('not valid');
    }
}
```

There are two aspects to consider: One is telling Ajax to perform synchronously (by setting async: false) and the other is returning result after check the response.

You did't mention any type like GET or POST method of ajax calling. I set it by calling GET but you also tried it with POST.

Comment: Did you check the response.data values and is it right value or not? The file serverTime.php which type type of values returned? I think there is no timing problem for getting response because of  jqxhr(deffer).

Comment: response.date returning correct value. The serverTime.php contains the following : <?php 
$now = new DateTime(); 
echo $now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n"; 
?>